# PMOSFET Ideal Diode for 24V

Tags: transistors

After some browsing I found transistor circuit very similar to my needs: 
[Understanding an 'ideal' diode made from a p-channel MOSFET and PNP transistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223935/understanding-an-ideal-diode-made-from-a-p-channel-mosfet-and-pnp-transistors)
Unfortunately its application is limited by the Emitter-Base breakdown voltage of used PNP transistors. Does anybody know similar circuits for 24V? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be with P-MOS? Is N-MOS acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffAU9c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can you work with a discrete version with a higher PIV rating for D2?

Comment: Yes, D2 is not a problem. Will try. Thank you for help :-)

Comment: D2 and Q1 must be carefully matched I think, or am I missing something?

Comment: good point... D2 must be a small,signal diode such that ; Vf of D2 >= Vbe of Q1@1mA at all times when input is 24V and output is also 24V , the desired operating point for switching