# Emitter-base voltage in ideal-diode circuit for voltages >5V

Tags: power-supply

I stumbled over the circuit in the related [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223935/understanding-an-ideal-diode-made-from-a-p-channel-mosfet-and-pnp-transistors) which accroding to the explanation and my understanding implements a comparator by means of two PNP transistors to pull the gate of the P-channels MOSFET.

I would like adapt the circuit select between multiple voltages sources of in the range of 4.5V - 24V like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ2u8e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My issue is that is seems that when the input voltages differ largely like 5V at input 1 and 24V at input 2, the emitter-base voltage of Q2 becomes quite large, exceeding the maximum rating of the BJT. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: check the answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/290284/pmosfet-ideal-diode-for-24v)

Comment: What do you mean "select between multiple sources?" Do you mean to select the highest voltage of them? Or will there only be one of them active at a time?

Comment: I mean to select the highest of two which can be active at the same time